# Dynamically Change CSS with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a snippet of code in which I would like to change the css dynamically based on the values being greater than 0. For a value of '0' the class = 'cart-summary__count'. For a value greater than '0' class = 'cart-summary__count_full'.

```
<span class="cart-summary__count" data-v-observable="cart-count">0</span>

<span class="cart-summary__count" data-v-observable="cart-count">1</span>
```

*edit:

```
<div id="cart-summary">
  <span class="cart-summary__count" data-v-observable="cart-count">0</span>
  <a href class="cart">example.com</a>
</div>
```

change to:

```
<a href class="cart-full">example.com</a>
```

I am still learning Js and any help would be greatly appreciated. The cart value can change on the page when adding an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").each(function(){
     if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 0){
       $(this).removeClass("cart-summary__count");
       $(this).addClass("cart-summary__count_full");
     }
  });
});
```

Refer this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/63/)

**Edit**

Based on your edit, use the following code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="cart-summary">
  <div class="cartContainer">
    <span class="cart-summary__count" data-v-observable="cart-count">0</span>
    <a href class="cart">example.com</a>  
  </div>
  <div class="cartContainer">
    <span class="cart-summary__count" data-v-observable="cart-count">1</span>
    <a href class="cart">example1.com</a>  
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").each(function(){
     if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 0){
            $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass("cart");
            $(this).parent().find('a').addClass("cart-full");
     }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.cart-full  {
  border : 2px solid red
}

.cartContainer {
  padding-top : 5px;
}
```

Refer New [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/64/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.I have removed id in your code as the id should be unique  and i have added a class cart-summary for all the spans.Once you run the below code it will append the required classes.

```js
$('#cart .cart-summary').each(function(){
  
  var span_value = parseInt($(this).text());
if(span_value == 0){
  $(this).addClass('cart-summary__count');
  }
  else{
 $(this).addClass('cart-summary__count_full');
}
  
  })
```

```css
.cart-summary__count{
  color:green;
  }
.cart-summary__count_full{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
<span class="cart-summary"  data-v-observable="cart-count">0</span>

<span class="cart-summary"  data-v-observable="cart-count">1</span>
<span class="cart-summary"  data-v-observable="cart-count">1</span>
<span class="cart-summary"  data-v-observable="cart-count">1</span>
<span class="cart-summary"  data-v-observable="cart-count">1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I did make a mistake in my original code block.

    <a href class="cart">example.com</a>
    <a href class="cart-full">example.com</a>